# Count NaNs when unicode values present

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, nan, python-unicode

Good morning all,

I have a `pandas` dataframe containing multiple series. For a given series within the dataframe, the datatypes are unicode, NaN, and int/float. I want to determine the number of NaNs in the series but cannot use the built in `numpy.isnan` method because it cannot safely cast unicode data into a format it can interpret. I have proposed a work around, but I'm wondering if there is a better/more Pythonic way of accomplishing this task.

Thanks in advance, 
Myles

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

test = pd.Series(data = [NaN, 2, u'string'])
np.isnan(test).sum()
#Error

#Work around
test2 = [x for x in test if not(isinstance(x, unicode))]
numNaNs = np.isnan(test2).sum()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [pandas.isnull](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.common.isnull.html):

```
In [24]: test = pd.Series(data = [NaN, 2, u'string'])

In [25]: pd.isnull(test)
Out[25]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Note however, that `pd.isnull` also regards `None` as `True`:

```
In [28]: pd.isnull([NaN, 2, u'string', None])
Out[28]: array([ True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate the prompt and complete response. (I'll accept your answer once the 10 minute wait expires)